# Where is the error page?

Tags: testing, grails, webdriver, functional-testing

https://bitbucket.org/refactor/grails-webdriver/wiki/Home says the following:

> If any failures occur, the current HTML is saved and linked to the
>   failure

I cannot see the saved HTML anywhere. Can someone tell me where it is?

> the app is really running and the tests interact with it through the
>   UI of a real (or simulated) web browser, just as a real user would

The way I read this, I should be able to see the browser going through the test steps. Is that correct? If it is, how do I get the browser to open up?

EDIT:

I am trying out this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/geb using the this sample project: https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You will be able to see a Browser working if your use the correct WebDriver for the real  Browser e.g. FireFoxDriver; if you use HtmlUnitDriver you will not see anything; it is a virtual Browser that exists only in memory.
- Screenshots can only be taken with WebDrivers that support the TakesScreenshot interface; HtmlUnitDriver does not.
- // run as “grails -Dgeb.env=firefox test-app”
- // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver
- On Windows 7 make sure you don't confuse the 32/64 bit Program Files (86x) folders.

Comment: That clarifies it a bit, thank you. I have tried using the firefox driver in the sample project I mentioned in the original question, but I just hangs on 'Running 1 functional test... 1 of 1'... any idea what might be the problem? I have firefox.exe in my PATH (on windows).

Comment: I'm not familiar with greb/grails but it seems like it is not finding Firefox to start, I would look into the config of that.